# Angled arrows TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want to create **angled arrows** for `x_2(t)` and `x_1(t)`. I would like the end of the arrow to be connected to `M1.east` and `M2.east` but still keep the direction of the arrow.

However the following code produces output which can be seen on the image.(angled arrows are still missing)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,  
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm]


\node (M1) [minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2cm] {$m_1$};
\node (M2) [minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2cm, yshift=-4cm] {$m_2$};
\node (ground) at (M2.south) [ground, yshift=-2cm,anchor=north] {};

\draw [spring] ($(M2.north east)+(-1,0cm)$)-- ($(M1.south east)+(-1,0cm)$) node[right=0.75cm, below=0.75cm] {$C_1$};
\draw [damper] ($(M2.north west)+(1,0cm)$)-- ($(M1.south west)+(1,0cm)$) node[left=1cm, below=0.75cm] {$B_1$};

\draw [spring] ($(ground.north east)+(-0.5,0cm)$)-- ($(M2.south east)+(-1,0cm)$) node[right=0.75cm, below=0.75cm] {$C_2$};
\draw [damper] ($(ground.north west)+(0.5,0cm)$)-- ($(M2.south west)+(1,0cm)$) node[left=1cm, below=0.75cm] {$B_2$};

\draw [-latex, ultra thick, <-] (M1.north) ++(0,0.1cm) -- +(0,1cm) node[below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$f(t)$};
\draw [-latex, ultra thick, ->] (M1.east) |- (M1.east) ++(0.5,0cm) -- +(0,1cm) node[below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_2(t)$};
\draw [-latex, ultra thick, ->] (M2.east) |- (M2.east) ++(0.5,0cm) -- +(0,1cm) node[below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_1(t)$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: tikz figure]

Comment: Please provide a full, compilable code; i.e. a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that people here can experiment with it. Not just a code snippet

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. It's now updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Please always add a full ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))!

---

**Answer:**

You can use `rounded corners=<inset>` ([TikZ and PGF manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de) *p.150*, chapter *14.5 Rounding Corners*) and shift the end position with `([xshift=2.25cm]M1.north)` (see *p.40*, *2.19 Transformations*).

The rounded `<inset>` describes how big the corner is. Here `rounded corners=5pt` is used.

*Angled arrows*:

```
\draw[rounded corners=5pt,-latex, ultra thick, ->,red] (M1.east) -|([xshift=2.25cm]M1.north)node[black,rounded corners=.0cm,below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_2(t)$}; 
\draw[rounded corners=5pt,-latex, ultra thick, ->,red] (M2.east) -|([xshift=2.25cm]M2.north)node[black,rounded corners=.0cm,below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_1(t)$};
```

*Solution:*

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,  
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm]


\node (M1) [minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2cm] {$m_1$};
\node (M2) [minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2cm, yshift=-4cm] {$m_2$};
\node (ground) at (M2.south) [ground, yshift=-2cm,anchor=north] {};

\draw [spring] ($(M2.north east)+(-1,0cm)$)-- ($(M1.south east)+(-1,0cm)$) node[right=0.75cm, below=0.75cm] {$C_1$};
\draw [damper] ($(M2.north west)+(1,0cm)$)-- ($(M1.south west)+(1,0cm)$) node[left=1cm, below=0.75cm] {$B_1$};

\draw [spring] ($(ground.north east)+(-0.5,0cm)$)-- ($(M2.south east)+(-1,0cm)$) node[right=0.75cm, below=0.75cm] {$C_2$};
\draw [damper] ($(ground.north west)+(0.5,0cm)$)-- ($(M2.south west)+(1,0cm)$) node[left=1cm, below=0.75cm] {$B_2$};

\draw [-latex, ultra thick, <-] (M1.north) ++(0,0.1cm) -- +(0,1cm) node[below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$f(t)$};
%\draw [-latex, ultra thick, ->] (M1.east) |- (M1.east) ++(0.5,0cm) -- +(0,1cm) node[below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_2(t)$};
%\draw [-latex, ultra thick, ->] (M2.east) |- (M2.east) ++(0.5,0cm) -- +(0,1cm) node[below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_1(t)$};
%
 \draw[rounded corners=5pt,-latex, ultra thick, ->,red] (M1.east) -|([xshift=2.25cm]M1.north)node[black,rounded corners=.0cm,below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_2(t)$}; 
 \draw[rounded corners=5pt,-latex, ultra thick, ->,red] (M2.east) -|([xshift=2.25cm]M2.north)node[black,rounded corners=.0cm,below=0.4cm, right=0.3cm] {$x_1(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```